# Add Image to the RSS plugin reader from another RSS

Tags: plugins, thumbnails

Hello there i need help with the "Super RSS Reader". It works great but i need add function to get image thumbnail from RSS description.

```
foreach ($rss_items as $item){
            // Get the link
            $link = $item->get_link();
            while ( stristr($link, 'http') != $link ){ $link = substr($link, 1); }
            $link = esc_url(strip_tags($link));

            // Get the item title
            $title = esc_attr(strip_tags($item->get_title()));
            if ( empty($title) )
                $title = __('Untitled');

            // Get the date
            $date = $item->get_date('j F Y');

            // Get the description
            $desc = str_replace( array("\n", "\r"), ' ', esc_attr( strip_tags( @html_entity_decode( $item->get_description(), ENT_QUOTES, get_option('blog_charset') ) ) ) );

            if($strip_desc != 0){
                $desc = wp_html_excerpt( $desc, $strip_desc );
                if ( '[...]' == substr( $desc, -5 ) )
                    $desc = substr( $desc, 0, -5 ) . '[&hellip;]';
                elseif ( '[&hellip;]' != substr( $desc, -10 ) )
                    $desc .= ' [&hellip;]';
            }
            $desc = esc_html( $desc );


            // Get the author
            $author = $item->get_author();
            if ( is_object($author) ) {
                $author = $author->get_name();
                $author = esc_html(strip_tags($author));
            }

            // Open links in new tab
            $newtab = ($open_newtab) ? ' target="_blank"' : '';

            echo "\n\n\t";

            // Display the feed items
            echo '<div class="srr-item ' . (($j%2 == 0) ? 'even' : 'odd') . '">';
            echo '<a href="' . $link . '"' . $newtab . ' title="Posted on ' . $date . '">' .$title . '</a>';
            if($show_date)      echo '<br/><em class="srr-date">' . $date . '</em>';
            if($show_author)    echo ' - <cite class="srr-author">' . $author . '</cite>';
            if($show_desc)      echo '<p class="srr-summary">' . $desc . '</p>';
            echo '</div>';
            // End display

            $j++;
        }
    }
```

Simply i need to add "get the image" part. i found some functions but i am not able implement them. I think many other which use the super rss reader will be happy to know how to add images from description and then display it on widgets. I also post question to creator but no answer so far.

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: The image is a part of the description tag in the xml and only usable via regex, not great and not performant. Also is this a way to change the content; not realy usefull for the authors of feeds.